# How to make a live time in JS?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to a make a live clock using JS Date();

*It seems freeze, until, I refresh the page.*

[image]

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date;

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('clock1').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock2').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock3').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock4').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock5').innerHTML = dateTime;
}, 1000)


var span = document.getElementsByClassName('time');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "DOTMBold";
  src: url("DOTMBold.TTF");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "LLPIXEL3";
  src: url("LLPIXEL3.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Technology";
  src: url("Technology.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "The Led Display St";
  src: url("The Led Display St.ttf");
}

#clock1 {
  font-family: "Calculator";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock2 {
  font-family: "DOTMBold";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock3 {
  font-family: "LLPIXEL3";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock4 {
  font-family: "Technology";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock5 {
  font-family: "The Led Display St";
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<title>hw18</title>

<div id="clock1"><span class="time"></span></div>
<div id="clock2"><span class="time"></span></div>
<div id="clock3"><span class="time"></span></div>
<div id="clock4"><span class="time"></span></div>
<div id="clock5"><span class="time"></span></div>
```

Comment: Any reason to not be using a library? Any data-binding framework will handle this with almost no code.

Comment: Which one you have in mind ? moment.js or jQuery ? I was trying to keep vanilla JS - for learning purpose.

Comment: Made you a snippet. Fix the console errors

Comment: You are only setting the initial `today` on pageload. The interval is running, it's just setting the innerHtml of the exact same string every time.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu–because it's not necessary?

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure what you mean with 'It's not necessary'... any library could be re-implemented using vanilla JS. 'I want to learn JS from scratch' or 'I do/want/can not add additional code' would be the answer I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move your date creation inside the interval. With your current solution, it will take the current date on startup and put it into the html every 1 second. But still the same date.

Here is a possible solution solution:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Just move your date creation inside the interval function
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + " " + time; // Add the time to the date string

  // Now it will take the current date and put it in all html elements
  document.getElementById('clock1').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock2').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock3').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock4').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock5').innerHTML = dateTime;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Love your solution man, it's like a magic, so I am very close after all;

Comment: @mplungjan I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: And what is `var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();`? @mplungjan

Comment: Just saw what you mean. He forgot to store time into `dateTime`. Thanks, fixed it, but next time if you really want to help stop speaking so cryptic. A simple `You forgot to add the time to dateTime` would have done wonders @mplungjan

Comment: 1) It is not "like" your code. Both our solutions are "like" the original code - because they are possible solution. 2) The question was not, how to pad digits.

Comment: It would have been less cryptic had you bothered to make a [mcve] - but never mind. My solution was also intended to educate OP and not just bugfixing.

Comment: Which is nice for a question, but definitely not needed for a simple answer pointing out a simple fix. Thank you anyways, but there is no need for that discussion now. @mplungjan

Answer (score 4):

Several issues

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('time');` is plural. It returns a collection. You need to loop over the span - but the spans are gone when you change the clockX innerHTML
2. You do not add the time to the dateTime
3. You likely want to pad the digits
4. You need to make a new date object for every call.

You likely want to do the following:

1. extract the time into its own function
2. pad the digits
3. now the spans are no longer needed but can be reinstated if necessary

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2)
const getTime = function() {
  var today = new Date();
  return `${today.getFullYear()}-${pad(today.getMonth() + 1)}-${pad(today.getDate())}
      ${pad(today.getHours())}:${pad(today.getMinutes())}:${pad(today.getSeconds())}`;

}

setInterval(function() {
  var dateTime = getTime()
  document.getElementById('clock1').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock2').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock3').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock4').innerHTML = dateTime;
  document.getElementById('clock5').innerHTML = dateTime;
}, 1000)
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "DOTMBold";
  src: url("DOTMBold.TTF");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "LLPIXEL3";
  src: url("LLPIXEL3.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Technology";
  src: url("Technology.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "The Led Display St";
  src: url("The Led Display St.ttf");
}

#clock1 {
  font-family: "Calculator";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock2 {
  font-family: "DOTMBold";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock3 {
  font-family: "LLPIXEL3";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock4 {
  font-family: "Technology";
  font-size: 70px;
}

#clock5 {
  font-family: "The Led Display St";
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<title>hw18</title>

<div id="clock1"></div>
<div id="clock2"></div>
<div id="clock3"></div>
<div id="clock4"></div>
<div id="clock5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your variable `var time` is overwriting the function `time()` so then the `setInterval` is using the wrong value for the first parameter.

Rename the function

```
function updateTime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```